# Mac Mini Server... Can I wipe it clean and use non-server edition?

Tags: macos, osx-server

As the title says. I have a Mac Mini server--I bought it because I liked the lack of a optical drive. I don't really care to use the software, and now having to spend an additional $50 on Lion's "Server" add-on is meh.

Can I wipe the machine clean and install a fresh 10.7, non-server edition?

Comment: So this is a pre-Lion Mac mini server?  You want to buy and install 10.7 clean?

Comment: I think you are looking for the [OS X Lion USB Thumb Drive](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD256Z/A?fnode=MTY1NDAzOA&mco=MTM3NDgwODM)?

Comment: Correct. 10.6 Server -> 10.7 Non-Server

Comment: You can easily use the 'non-server' version of OS X with no problems, since OS X server is just 1 app added onto the machine. I recommend you don't even bother with reinstalls and just delete the Server.app in your application folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went the route of loading the `InstallESD.dmg` file onto a USB thumb drive and booting from it (holding down the `option` key). This worked like a charm. No issues/unusual steps due it the system having 10.6 Server installed beforehand.

The directions I followed are from here: http://mashable.com/2011/07/20/lion-clean-install-guide/#20859Step-1-Download-Lion-From-the-Mac-App-Store

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  I am currently using a late 2009 Mac mini Server with both Snow Leopard and Lion (non-server editions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm only after seeing this post. I don't have time at the minute to answer it properly but if you haven't found a solution yet let me know and I'll give you all the details.

I had a 2009 MacMini SL Server. I tried to upgrade it to Lion Server and it upgraded but no server function worked properly and it was as slow as a dog.

I EVENTUALLY wiped the RAID disks and successfully installed Lion and then Server on top of it. It was much faster and the server functions worked just fine.

It's a little tricky but by no means Rocket Science.

Just let me know.